# Normalize conditional univariate seaborn by condition

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn, normalization

I would like to plot a conditional univariate histogram, while normalizing according to the conditioning variable (i.e. group). However, normalization by using `common_norm=False` seems to only work when a hue is assigned, by normalizing by the hue variable.

Without normalization:

```py
diamonds = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")
sns.histplot(diamonds, y="price", x="clarity", log_scale=(False, True))
```

[image: Output 1]

As you can see, some levels of clarity have fewer observations, and thus their distribution is not easily visualized.

I could simulate the behavior I wanted by assigning the hue variable to the same as the x variable.

```py
blue_palette = sns.color_palette(n_colors=1)
hist_ax = sns.histplot(diamonds, y="price", x="clarity", log_scale=(False, True), hue="clarity", palette=blue_palette, common_norm=False)
hist_ax.get_legend().remove()
```

[image: Output 2]

However, this has disadvantages, since it doesn't allow me to use the `thresh` or `cbar` parameters.

```py
hist_ax = sns.histplot(diamonds, y="price", x="clarity", log_scale=(False, True), hue="clarity", palette=blue_palette, common_norm=False, cbar=True)
```

[image: Output 3]

```py
hist_ax = sns.histplot(diamonds, y="price", x="clarity", log_scale=(False, True), hue="clarity", palette=blue_palette, common_norm=False, thresh=None)
```

[image: Output 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found an interesting way to turn seaborn's bivariate histplot into columns of univariate heatmap-like histograms.

The colorbar doesn't work well, as each hue value now has a separate range. You could just create one custom colorbar (using the colormap associated to the first hue value), and instead of exact values just put a text.

Setting `thresh=None` seems to choose some arbitrary default threshold, which doesn't fit your situation. You can set `thresh=10` to cut off counts below 10. Or `pthresh=0.05` to cut off counts below 5% of the maximum.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

diamonds = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
blue_palette = ['blue'] * len(diamonds["clarity"].unique()) # or 'dodgerblue', which is closer to the original
ax = sns.histplot(diamonds, y="price", x="clarity", log_scale=(False, True), hue="clarity", palette=blue_palette,
                  common_norm=False, cbar=False, legend=False, thresh=10)
cbar = plt.colorbar(ax.collections[0], ticks=[], label='counts')
for text, y in zip(["none", "many"], [0.02, 0.98]):
    cbar.ax.text(1.2, y, text, transform=cbar.ax.transAxes, ha='left', va='center')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot]

Note that areas with zero count get the "bad" color of the colormap. You can set that color the same as the "under" color to have everything filled.

The adapted code also removes the white space around the plot (`ax.margins(x=0,y=0)`).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

diamonds = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
blue_palette = ['dodgerblue'] * len(diamonds["clarity"].unique())
ax = sns.histplot(diamonds, y="price", x="clarity", log_scale=(False, True), hue="clarity", palette=blue_palette,
                  common_norm=False, cbar=False, legend=False, thresh=0)
ax.collections[0].cmap.set_bad(ax.collections[0].cmap.get_under())
cbar = plt.colorbar(ax.collections[0], ticks=[], label='counts')
for text, y in zip(["none", "many"], [0.02, 0.98]):
    cbar.ax.text(1.2, y, text, transform=cbar.ax.transAxes, ha='left', va='center')
ax.margins(x=0, y=0)
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: 2d sns.histplot used in 1d]

Comment: Thank you for the solutions! However, as to the threshold parameter: what I intended to was to use `thres=None` to make it so that squares with no observations use the faintest color hue, instead of being left as white squares. Do you think that would be possible?

Comment: I updated the code to also fill the white area. Note that `thress=None` is some small value, not `0`.